# Global object in DotVVM (for masterpage)

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, dotvvm

I'm looking for some global object in DotVVM framework as ViewBag in Asp.Net MVC. I wanna have a masterpage with dynamic title and I don't know how could I do this.

For example: In asp.net MVC "ViewBag.Title" -> where Title is property from view(model) and when I am changing articles, title changes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have nothing like `ViewBag` in [DotVVM](https://www.dotvvm.com). However, all viewmodels of pages which use the master page, must inherit from the viewmodel of the master page, so just place the `Title` property in the master page's viewmodel and you'll have it available in all content pages. You can set it e.g. in the constructor of each viewmodel.